# Disabling sms delivery report globally in android

Tags: sms, permissions

I know we can enable/disable the sms delivery report in the messaging app.
But is it possible to disable it for all apps?

I use an app that sends sms to control a device and I guess it's using the delivery report and does not have anything in its settings to disable the usage of the delivery report, which gets charged additionally by the mobile operator. I would like to be able to deny the app to use the sms delivery report by using android settings or some additional tool(s).

Comment: well, I guess my problem was solved by contacting the operator and disabling the reports on the operator side. But this question might still be useful for users who would  like to control the delivery reports per-app, I think.

Comment: What android version are you using?

Comment: Currently - 5.1.1., but a universal solution would be more beneficial, because people change devices and android versions sometimes.

Comment: The path to a possible solution maybe different per android version and/or device manufacturer. One thing may be revoke sms permissions of the app.

Comment: Well, I will not be able to test that anymore, sorry. Since the reports are blocked by the operator.